# Heroku and mongoHQ: Connection failed

Tags: mongodb, heroku, mongoose, mongohq

I have the following environment variable on Heroku :

```
MONGOHQ_URL: mongodb://heroku:password%40mongohq%2Estaff%2Ecom:10056/app6186345
```

Originally the error was :

```
Database name cannot contain '.'
```

I escaped '.' and '@'and I still have the same result, a connection failed but with the message :

```
[Error: failed to connect to [heroku:27017]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I checked the documentation about mongoHQ, nothing is said about escaping caracters or something equivalent.

Comment: I don't encode my connection and it works for me.  Do you have a . or @ in your password by chance?  Also, it's probably a copy/paste, but that url for mongohq is backwards, can you verify that?

Comment: No @ or . in my password.. this url is backward?

Comment: Also, if you go to your database in mongohq and click on the Database Info tab there are two samples on how to connect.  Does logging in with the mongo shell work?

Comment: it should be "@staff.mongohq.com" not "@mongohq.staff.com"

Comment: It works using the mongo shell...

Comment: wow wait, it likes it was the problem, let me check why I had that.

Comment: blu, if you want, put your propositions as an answer and I accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have reversed the subdomain and domain name for mongohq on accident.

It should be `@staff.mongohq.com` instead of `@mongohq.staff.com`

Comment: Yes, I agree. That is the issue that you are seeing. I am not sure why it would be working via mongoshell. Can you share output?